# Fastest way to implode an associative array with keys

Tags: php, arrays, query-string, associative-array, implode

I'm looking for a fast way to turn an associative array in to a string. Typical structure would be like a URL query string but with customizable separators so I can use '`&amp;`' for xhtml links or '`&`' otherwise.

My first inclination is to use `foreach` but since my method could be called many times in one request I fear it might be too slow.

```
<?php
$Amp = $IsXhtml ? '&amp;' : '&';
$Parameters = array('Action' => 'ShowList', 'Page' => '2');
$QueryString = '';
foreach ($Parameters as $Key => $Value)
        $QueryString .= $Amp . $Key . '=' . $Value;
```

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Don't forget if you are outputting HTML, the correct syntax is &amp; not &, iow this is wrong <a href="?name=joe&age=22">JOE</a> yes it works but it's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You can use [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query) to do that.

> Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

Comment: Was trying to find this method in the PHP API myself this is definitely the way to go. If not the alternative is to use a modified implode method such as http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php#84684 but http_build_query() will properly be faster.

Comment: I wonder if this is really the fastest way for the general question.  There is some encoding going on in this function. So, if it's not for a URL, is this really faster than array_walk and what if you don't want it encoded?

Comment: the problem is `http_build_query` escape special char

Comment: I've compared serialize(), json_encode() and http_build_query().
http_build_query() won by a slight margin over serialize(), and json_encode being the slowest by far.

Comment: It also encodes special characters, so this is not a good option

Comment: to commenters, what if you don't need any special chars? Then this solution is perfect

Answer (score 46):

If you're not concerned about the *exact* formatting however you do want something simple but without the line breaks of `print_r` you can also use `json_encode($value)` for a quick and simple formatted output. (*note it works well on other data types too*)

```
$str = json_encode($arr);
//output...
[{"id":"123","name":"Ice"},{"id":"234","name":"Cake"},{"id":"345","name":"Pie"}]
```

Answer (score 36):

As an aside, I was in search to find the best way to implode an associative array but using my own seperators etc...

So I did this using PHP's array_walk() function to let me join an associative array into a list of parameters that could then be applied to a HTML tag....

```
// Create Params Array
$p = Array("id"=>"blar","class"=>"myclass","onclick"=>"myJavascriptFunc()");

// Join Params
array_walk($p, create_function('&$i,$k','$i=" $k=\"$i\"";'));
$p_string = implode($p,"");

// Now use $p_string for your html tag
```

Obviously, you could stick that in your own function somehow but it gives you an idea of how you can join an associative array using your own method.
Hope that helps someone :)

Comment: If the syntax of create_function is confusing anyone, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Comment: array_walk is slower from foreach and more complicated for read. See this: http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1uuc34/quick_test_to_see_if_array_walk_is_better_than/

Comment: Found this version useful as the first solution as http_build_query() encodes URLs.

Answer (score 24):

This is my solution for example for an div data-attributes:

```
<?

$attributes = array(
    'data-href'   => 'http://example.com',
    'data-width'  => '300',
    'data-height' => '250',
    'data-type'   => 'cover',
);

$dataAttributes = array_map(function($value, $key) {
    return $key.'="'.$value.'"';
}, array_values($attributes), array_keys($attributes));

$dataAttributes = implode(' ', $dataAttributes);

?>

<div class="image-box" <?= $dataAttributes; ?> >
    <img src="http://example.com/images/best-of.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 21):

One way is using `print_r(array, true)` and it will return string representation of array

Comment: $request_str=print_r($_REQUEST,true);  // flatten array for log file

Comment: But that outputs in the print_r format, not as `key=value` joined with a supplied separator.

Answer (score 9):

My solution:

```
$url_string = http_build_query($your_arr);
$res = urldecode($url_string);
```

Comment: i liked this approach as it looks simpler than other long codes. though this is not exactly what we are after.. we look for this format : "key: value\r\n...." so i used this fomula : to get that urldecode(str_replace("=", ": ", http_build_query($headers,"", "\r\n"))). look below for this as proposed solution.

Answer (score 3):

What about this shorter, more transparent, yet more intuitive with array_walk

```
$attributes = array(
  'data-href'   => 'http://example.com',
  'data-width'  => '300',
  'data-height' => '250',
  'data-type'   => 'cover',
);

$args = "";
array_walk(
    $attributes, 
    function ($item, $key) use (&$args) {
        $args .= $key ." = '" . $item . "' ";  
    }
);
// output: 'data-href="http://example.com" data-width="300" data-height="250" data-type="cover"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_to_attributes ( $array_attributes )
{

    $attributes_str = NULL;
    foreach ( $array_attributes as $attribute => $value )
    {

        $attributes_str .= " $attribute=\"$value\" ";

    }

    return $attributes_str;
}

$attributes = array(
    'data-href'   => 'http://example.com',
    'data-width'  => '300',
    'data-height' => '250',
    'data-type'   => 'cover',
);

echo array_to_attributes($attributes) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner for creating string of HTML attributes (with quotes) from a simple array:

```
$attrString = str_replace("+", " ", str_replace("&", "\" ", str_replace("=", "=\"", http_build_query($attrArray)))) . "\"";
```

## Example:

```
$attrArray = array("id"    => "email", 
                   "name"  => "email",
                   "type"  => "email",
                   "class" => "active large");

echo str_replace("+", " ", str_replace("&", "\" ", str_replace("=", "=\"", http_build_query($attrArray)))) . "\"";

// Output:
// id="email" name="email" type="email" class="active large"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_walk` for this.

```
$arr = [
    "key"  => "value",
    "key2" => "value2",
];

array_walk($arr, function(&$value, $key) {
    $value = "{$key}: {$value}";
});

implode("<br/>", $arr)
```

**Result**

```
key: value<br/>key2: value2<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked the approach of @kostikovmu as it looks simpler than other long codes. though this is not exactly what we are after..
We look for this header format : "...key: value\r\n...".

So i used extended the fomula to get that

```
urldecode(str_replace("=", ": ", http_build_query($headers,"", "\r\n")))
```