# Whats the best way to manage QUERY_STRING in php?

Tags: php, optimization, query-string

One of my sites has some very complicated sorting functions, on top of a pagination, and the various variables add up to a pretty complex URL, which is a huge pain to manage. Is there a way to manage the QUERY_STRING efficiently?

By this I mean... if the url is index.php?catid=3&sort=date&year=2009&page=2 and I wish to have the user jump to page 3, or change the sort method..... how would I preserve the remaining vars without checking for each individual var with an if/else condition and echo them out in the link that would link to page 3 or alternate sort method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle actual query **strings** (string format), you can use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str). When you want to build a query string, use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query).

There's quite a few examples on those documentation pages.

If for some reason you can't use `http_build_query`, check out my question about the [fastest way to implode an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408032/fastest-way-to-implode-an-associative-array-with-keys).

```
<?php
$QueryString = 'catid=3&sort=date&year=2009&page=2'; // sample querystring
parse_str($QueryString, $HttpQuery);

print_r($HttpQuery); // will be an associative array

$HttpQuery['page'] = 3; // change any values

$NewQueryString = http_build_query($HttpQuery); // rebuild the querystring
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP supplies you a global $_GET which holds your query string all nicely parsed into elements

```
$_GET['catid'] will be '3'
$_GET['sort'] will be 'date'
$_GET['year'] will be '2009'
```

etc

You could unset the ones you don't want to pass along and then move to new url via something like:

```
$get = array_intersect_key($_GET, array_keys($_GET));
unset($get['sort']);
$url = 'target.php?' . http_build_query($get);
```

Comment: -1, that implode will not preserve the keys, it only joins the values together.

Comment: What should $_GET.slice() do? That's not PHP as $_GET is an array and therefore has no methods to call.

Comment: yep / brain fart - too many languages in use in my head these days

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you would like that the link to page 3 would be only

```
index.php?page=3
```

or link to changing the sort method would be only

```
index.php?sort=date
```

You would have to store the other variables in [session variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) (or cookies, if you want them to persist longer).

Something like this:

```
<?php
  
  session_start();
  
  foreach($_GET as $var => $val) {
    // filter any malicious stuff and invalid variables out of $var and $val here
    // like
    if (in_array($var, $array_of_valid_variable_names)) {
      if ($var == 'page') $val = intval($val);

      $_SESSION[$var] = $val;
    }
  }

  // do stuff based on the values stored in $_SESSION

  echo '<a href="index.php?page='.($_SESSION['page'] + 1).'">Next page</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although most of the solutions provided here will work, I think the most simple way to do this will be

```
// parse query string into an array
$queryData = array();
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $queryData);
/*
 * ... manipulate array $queryData
 */
// rebuild query string
$queryString = http_build_query($queryData, null, '&amp;'); // or use & if you don't need XHTML compliance
```

That's it. Please see documentation on [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) and [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) (that's one of those functions whose name was completey messed up - nobody would expect the function to do what it does just by looking at the name).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the exact same problem with a general "build me a sortable, pageable Table" class. This is why someone invented subprocedures called "functions" in php.

You have to create a function that handles exactly the link-building process. like so:

```
/**
* $set: associative array of changing vars
* $unset : normal array of vars to delete
**/
function get_link($set,$unset=array())
{
 $set+=$_GET;
 if ($unset && is_array($unset))
   foreach($unset as $idx) 
      unset($set[$idx]);

 if ($set)
   foreach($set as $name=>$value)
      $pairs[]=$name.'='.urlencode($value);

 return $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']."?".join('&',$pairs);
}
```

UNTESTED CODE! Use your brains

or you could use $_SESSION-vars for pageing and sorting (an' stuff) and have links only change those (which is what i mostly do nowadays)

Answer (score 0):

Add the variable name and value at the end of the query string (changing page to 3):

```
index.php?catid=3&sort=date&year=2009&page=2&x=page&y=3
```

Then, after extracting $_GET, use a simple function to check if x and y are set.

If they are, set the variable whose name is contained in x to the value y.

You can use the same link everywhere with a simple addition at the end, and the amount of programming is minimal.

Comment: Interesting solution, but it makes things too complicated and causes duplicate pages to be generated, not good for SEO.

Answer (score -1):

Don't manage the string directly but manage an array ( key => value ) representation of it and only translate it back to string when needed.

One possible way of doing it:

```
function explodeQueryString( $queryString )
{
    $parts = array();
    if ( strlen( $queryString ) > 1 && substr( $queryString, 0, 1 ) == '?' )
    {
        $q = explode( '&', substr( $queryString, 1 ) );
        foreach( $q as $part )
        {
            list( $key, $value ) = explode( '=', $part );
            $parts[ urldecode( $key ) ] = urldecode( $value );
        }
    }
    return $parts;
}

function implodeQueryString( array $arguments )
{
    $parts = array();
    foreach( $arguments as $key => $value )
    {
        $parts[ ] = sprintf( '%s=%s', urlencode( $key ), urlencode( $value ) );
    }
    return sprintf( '?%s', implode( '&', $parts ) );
}

// $query = $_GET;

$query = '?something=1&somethingelse=2&page=1&yetsomethingelse=3';

$q = explodeQueryString( $query );

print_r( $q );

$q[ 'page' ] += 1;

$query = implodeQueryString( $q );

echo $query;
```

Comment: i know there is $_GET but that's only for the current request. sometimes you need to parse arbitrary amounts of querystrings.

Comment: This is exactly what parse_str() and http_build_query() do natively.