# How to implode array with key and value without foreach in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

**Without foreach**, 
how can I turn an array like this

```
array("item1"=>"object1", "item2"=>"object2",......."item-n"=>"object-n");
```

to a string like this

```
item1='object1', item2='object2',.... item-n='object-n'
```

I thought about `implode()` already, but it doesn't implode the key with it.

If foreach it necessary, is it possible to not nest the foreach?

**EDIT:** I've changed the string

---

**EDIT2/UPDATE:** 
This question was asked quite a while ago. At that time, I wanted to write everything in one line so I would use ternary operators and nest built in function calls in favor of foreach. That was not a good practice! Write code that is readable, whether it is concise or not doesn't matter that much.

In this case: putting the foreach in a function will be much more readable and modular than writing a one-liner(Even though all the answers are great!).

Comment: How nested foreach would be necesarry?

Comment: What are you attempting? Why do you have those constraints?

Comment: this was my database class for web app i'm building, i don't want it to look messy since it's already populated with a bunch of foreach and  for-loop all together

Comment: This selected answer is method that you asked for, however it should be noted that it is critically slower and that if you are storing this information via a database it would be vastly superior to both a loop and this to just use json_encode.  Exhibit A: http://willem.stuursma.name/2010/11/22/a-detailed-look-into-array_map-and-foreach/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fastest way to implode an associative array with keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408032/fastest-way-to-implode-an-associative-array-with-keys)

Answer (score 213, accepted):

and another way:

```
$input = array(
    'item1'  => 'object1',
    'item2'  => 'object2',
    'item-n' => 'object-n'
);

$output = implode(', ', array_map(
    function ($v, $k) {
        if(is_array($v)){
            return $k.'[]='.implode('&'.$k.'[]=', $v);
        }else{
            return $k.'='.$v;
        }
    }, 
    $input, 
    array_keys($input)
));
```

or:

```
$output = implode(', ', array_map(
    function ($v, $k) { return sprintf("%s='%s'", $k, $v); },
    $input,
    array_keys($input)
));
```

Comment: This method is what the Author was asking for, but it should be noted that it is critically slower and that if you are storing this information via a database it would be vastly superior to both a loop and this to just use json_encode.  Exhibit A: http://willem.stuursma.name/2010/11/22/a-detailed-look-into-array_map-and-foreach/

Comment: None of the links here seem to work anymore, they all `echo "Hello, World!";` Should I be seeing code examples of those functions?

Comment: This method is very easy to customize according to own demand.

Comment: I was using this method to build select options and populate the selected option, and since both arrays must be the same size you can do something like this for the second array.
`array_fill(0, $input, 'selected-value-you want-to-check-against');` This will generate same size array with single value for all the rows.

Answer (score 252):

You could use [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query), like this:

```
<?php
  $a=array("item1"=>"object1", "item2"=>"object2");
  echo http_build_query($a,'',', ');
?>
```

Output:

```
item1=object1, item2=object2
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vfKClP)

Comment: is it possible to make the object1 into 'object1'

Comment: Beware of the string encoding!If you are not building an URL maybe you do not want it on your array key&value

Comment: @Matteo You can wrap `http_build_query` in `urldecode` to avoid it.

Comment: Genius solution. That was all I needed for a debug output of am assoc array.

Comment: Anyway to omit `key` itself?

Comment: One should be aware of how the 4th parameter handles white space.

Comment: It changes your values if have space in it. The `http_build_query` replaces spaces with plus (`+` ) character.

Comment: Just because you can use a brick to hammer in a nail, does not mean you should. Someone may change the shape of the brick not thinking someone is using it in place of a hammer. Use the correct tools for the job, for future-proofing a solution.

Answer (score 55):

I spent measurements (100000 iterations), what fastest way to glue an associative array?

**Objective:** To obtain a line of 1,000 items, in this format: "key:value,key2:value2"

We have array (for example):

```
$array = [
    'test0' => 344,
    'test1' => 235,
    'test2' => 876,
    ...
];
```

**Test number one:**

Use **http_build_query** and **str_replace**:

```
str_replace('=', ':', http_build_query($array, null, ','));
```

Average time to implode 1000 elements: 0.00012930955084904

**Test number two:**

Use **array_map** and **implode**:

```
implode(',', array_map(
        function ($v, $k) {
            return $k.':'.$v;
        },
        $array,
        array_keys($array)
    ));
```

Average time to implode 1000 elements: 0.0004890081976675

**Test number three:**

Use **array_walk** and **implode**:

```
array_walk($array,
        function (&$v, $k) {
            $v = $k.':'.$v;
        }
    );
implode(',', $array);
```

Average time to implode 1000 elements: 0.0003874126245348

**Test number four:**

Use **foreach**:

```
    $str = '';
    foreach($array as $key=>$item) {
        $str .= $key.':'.$item.',';
    }
    rtrim($str, ',');
```

Average time to implode 1000 elements: 0.00026632803902445

**I can conclude that the best way to glue the array - use http_build_query and str_replace**

Comment: `$s = ''; foreach ($array as $k=>$v) { if ($s !== null) { $s .= ','; } $s .= "{$k}:{$v}"; }` outperforms all others.

Comment: The http_build_query bench is missing urldecode to be comparative to the others.

Comment: Another option: `substr(str_replace('"', '', json_encode($headers)), 1, -1);`

Comment: CAUTION: It changes your values if have space in it. The `http_build_query` replaces spaces with plus (`+` ) character.

Comment: I just tested `http_build_query`+`urldecode` vs implode. Implode was 10 times faster.

Answer (score 14):

I would use `serialize()` or `json_encode()`.

While it won't give your the exact result string you want, it would be much easier to encode/store/retrieve/decode later on.

Answer (score 4):

Using [array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk)

```
$a = array("item1"=>"object1", "item2"=>"object2","item-n"=>"object-n");
$r=array();
array_walk($a, create_function('$b, $c', 'global $r; $r[]="$c=$b";'));
echo implode(', ', $r);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/W9Sdv)

Comment: I like the array_walk approach, but I don't understand why people suggest using `create_function` instead of just using an anonymous function?

Comment: @Rikki Compatibility!

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise it was a PHP4 thing!

Comment: @Rikki **No**. Its pre PHP 5.3 thing. [Anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) first appeared on PHP 5.3

Comment: **But** it was introduced in PHP 4.0.1, so is a PHP4 thing. Semantics... Adding a feature as significant as anonymous functions in a minor version update is bizarre.

Answer (score 4):

You could use PHP's [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) as well,

```
$a = ['Name' => 'Last Name'];

function acc($acc,$k)use($a){ return $acc .= $k.":".$a[$k].",";}

$imploded = array_reduce(array_keys($a), "acc");
```

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
-    return substr($result, (-1 * strlen($glue)));
+    return substr($result, 0, -1 * strlen($glue));
```

if you want to resive the entire String without the last $glue

```
function key_implode(&$array, $glue) {
    $result = "";
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result .= $key . "=" . $value . $glue;
    }
    return substr($result, (-1 * strlen($glue)));
}
```

And the usage:

```
$str = key_implode($yourArray, ",");
```

Comment: why are you using a reference array in key_implode?

Comment: you should return `substr($result, 0, strlen($result) - strlen($glue))`, because your substr will only return the glue value

Answer (score 3):

For debugging purposes. Recursive write an array of nested arrays to a string.
Used foreach. Function stores National Language characters.

```
function q($input)
{
    $glue = ', ';
    $function = function ($v, $k) use (&$function, $glue) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $arr = [];
            foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
                $arr[] = $function($value, $key);
            }
            $result = "{" . implode($glue, $arr) . "}";
        } else {
            $result = sprintf("%s=\"%s\"", $k, var_export($v, true));
        }
        return $result;
    };
    return implode($glue, array_map($function, $input, array_keys($input))) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example, using class:

```
$input = array(
    'element1'  => 'value1',
    'element2'  => 'value2',
    'element3' =>  'value3'
);

echo FlatData::flatArray($input,', ', '=');

class FlatData
{

    public static function flatArray(array $input = array(), $separator_elements = ', ', $separator = ': ')
    {
        $output = implode($separator_elements, array_map(
            function ($v, $k, $s) {
                return sprintf("%s{$s}%s", $k, $v);
            },
            $input,
            array_keys($input),
            array_fill(0, count($input), $separator)
        ));
      return $output;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

For create mysql where conditions from array

```
$sWheres = array('item1'  => 'object1',
                 'item2'  => 'object2',
                 'item3'  => 1,
                 'item4'  => array(4,5),
                 'item5'  => array('object3','object4'));
$sWhere = '';
if(!empty($sWheres)){
    $sWhereConditions = array();
    foreach ($sWheres as $key => $value){
        if(!empty($value)){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $value = array_filter($value); // For remove blank values from array
                if(!empty($value)){
                    array_walk($value, function(&$item){ $item = sprintf("'%s'", $item); }); // For make value string type 'string'
                    $sWhereConditions[] = sprintf("%s in (%s)", $key, implode(', ', $value));
                }
            }else{
                $sWhereConditions[] = sprintf("%s='%s'", $key, $value);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!empty($sWhereConditions)){
        $sWhere .= "(".implode(' AND ', $sWhereConditions).")";
    }
}
echo $sWhere;  // (item1='object1' AND item2='object2' AND item3='1' AND item4 in ('4', '5') AND item5 in ('object3', 'object4'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Short one:

```
$string = implode('; ', array_map(fn($k, $v) => "$k=$v", array_keys($array), $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using explode to get an array from any string is always OK, because array is an always in standard structure.

But about array to string, is there any reason to use predefined string in codes? while the string SHOULD be in any format to use!

The good point of foreach is that you can create the string AS YOU NEED IT!
I'd suggest still using foreach quiet readable and clean.

```
$list = array('a'=>'1', 'b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3');

$sql_val = array();
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
    $sql_val[] = "(" . $key . ", '" . $value . "') ";
}
$sql_val = implode(', ', $sql_val);
```

with results:

```
(a, '1') , (b, '2') , (c, '3')
```

|

```
(a: '1') , (b: '2') , (c: '3')
```

|

```
a:'1' , b:'2' , c:'3'
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution to this question and I know it's been 10 years old but halfway the page, I thought: why not string replace on a json encode. It will give you easy access on how to configure the string. Also, it's a oneliner that avoids a (foreach) loop.

It would look something like this:

```
$wrapperAttributesString = str_replace(['{"' , '"}', '":', '","'],['' , '', '=', ' '], json_encode($wrapperAttributes));
```

So, bassically what happens here is:

```
$wrapperAttributes['class'] = 'hi__stack--overflow';
$wrapperAttributes['style'] = 'overflow: stack; ';
$wrapperAttributes['id']    = 'oneliner_array_with_keys_tostring_attributes';

//if we were to json encode this array: it would result in this:
// {"class":"hi__stack--overflow","style":"overflow: stack; ","id":"oneliner_array_with_keys_tostring_attributes"}
```

now the str_replace first argument takes an array with find what, the second is an array to replace that with.
so it does:

find {" and replace with nothing;

find }" and replace with nothing;

find ": and replace with =;

find "," and replace with " ; to close the attribute and space to chain next

the output would be

> class="hi__stack--overflow" style="overflow: stack; "
> id="oneliner_array_with_keys_tostring_attributes"

Now if you woud like to have comma separated instead of space separated string, just change the last replace into find "," with ','

the output would become

> class="hi__stack--overflow",style="overflow: stack;
> ",id="oneliner_array_with_keys_tostring_attributes

**Be aware**, that this might be safe for html attributes (considering the values should never have a doubleqoute), but I would definitly **not** use it where the values can have the same combinations as the replaces have.

This is my first post, so, if you have any feedback. Feel free to let me know, also, if I by accident, did not abide by any standards, then let me know and i wil change it asap :)

Answer (score -1):

Also if the question is outdated and the solution not requested anymore, I just found myself in the need of printing an array for debugging purposes (throwing an exception and showing the array that caused the problem).

For this reason, I anyway propose my simple solution (one line, like originally asked):

```php
$array = ['a very' => ['complex' => 'array']];
$imploded = var_export($array, true);
```

This will return the exported var instead of directly printing it on the screen and the var $imploded will contain the full export.