# Is it possible to implode two different arrays in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$firstName = array_unique($name[1]);
$lastName = array_unique($name[0]);
echo "".implode("<br>",First name: $firstName)." ".implode("<br>",Last name: $lastName)."";
```

I want the output to be like:

First name: $firstName[0]  Last name: $lastName[0]; 
First name: $firstName[1]  Last name: $lastName[1]; 
etc.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo join('<br>', array_map(
    function ($first, $last) { return "First name: $first Last name: $last"; },
    $firstName,
    $lastName
));
```

Note that the `$firstName` and `$lastName` arrays ***must*** be the same length. I'm not sure this is guaranteed in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You could [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) them first ending up with an associative array and then use the approach explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427398/php-how-to-implode-array-with-key-and-value-without-foreach).

`implode(', ', array_map(function ($v, $k) { return $k . '=' . $v; }, $input, array_keys($input)));`

Answer (score 0):

Why to complicate

```
$s="";
foreach(array_unique($name) as $name){
    $s .= "<br>First name: {$name[1]} Last name: {$name[0]}";
}
```