# split array into comma separated values

Tags: php

I have an array `$email` like this:

```
Array
(
    [email_id] => bob2@example.com
)
Array
(
    [email_id] => bob3@example.com
)
Array
(
    [email_id] => bob4@example.com
)
```

I need this array to be in this format

```
'bob2@example.com', 'bob3@example.com', 'bob4@example.com' // RESULT EXPECTED
```

I am doing this to get my result:

```
$emails = implode(", " , $email);
```

But it results in this:

```
bob2@example.combob3@example.combob4@example.com // ACTUAL RESULT
```

What should i do get the result?

Comment: Its difficult to use `implode` since all array keys are same. `implode` will work if the array is like `array('mail1', 'mail2')`. For the time being, use the solution put forward by @Hassan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php how to implode array with key and value without foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427398/php-how-to-implode-array-with-key-and-value-without-foreach)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$email = array(
    array('email_id' => 'bob2@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob3@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob4@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob5@gmail.com'),
    );

foreach($email as $id)
{
    echo "'".$id['email_id']."',";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hassaan this works. but can it be like: 'bob2@gmail.com', 'bob3@gmail.com', 'bob4@gmail.com' . As now it is coming as bob2@gmail.com, bob3@gmail.com, bob4@gmail.com. Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks. It gives result with a coma after last email also. like this: 'bob2@gmail.com','bob3@gmail.com','bob4@gmail.com', which is wrong. I dont need comma at last.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Hassaan's technique :

```
$email = array(
    array('email_id' => 'bob2@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob3@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob4@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob5@gmail.com'),
);

foreach($email as $id){
    $emails .= $id['email_id'].",";
}

$emails = substr($emails, 0, strlen($emails) -1 );

echo $emails;
```

With this technique you will not have the last comma.

Or you can use this technique that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710800/implode-data-from-a-multi-dimensional-array)

```
$input = array(
    array('email_id' => 'bob2@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob3@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob4@gmail.com'),
    array('email_id' => 'bob5@gmail.com')
);

echo implode(',', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry['email_id'];
}, $input));
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange!! It should work.

How you have defined your `$email` array? Can you provide a code structure?

If you have something like this then it will definitely work.

```
$email = array('email1','email2');
echo implode(", ",$email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try php's csv function for it

```
<?php

 $file = fopen("email.csv","w");

 foreach ($yourArray as $value)
   {
   fputcsv($file,explode(',',$value));
   }

 fclose($file); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to reduce the array of arrays into just an array of strings.

```
$actualEmails = array_map (function ($e) {
    return $e ['email_id'];
}, $email);
echo "'" . implode ("','", $actualEmails) . "'";
```