# Convert PHP array into HTML tag attributes separated by spaces

Tags: php, html, tags

I need to convert a PHP array into HTML tag attributes, with spaces and quotes, this is an example:

```
$array=array(
    'attr1'=>'value1',
    'id'=>'example',
    'name'=>'john',
    'class'=>'normal'
);
```

This is the result I need to achieve:

```
attr1="value1" id="example" name="john" class="normal"
```

There is any PHP function to do it?

I am trying these:

- http_build_query
- array_walk

Comment: Take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427398/how-to-implode-array-with-key-and-value-without-foreach-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implode array with key and value without foreach in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427398/how-to-implode-array-with-key-and-value-without-foreach-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use this easy one line code, please follwo below code::

```
$array=array(
    'attr1'=>'value1',
    'id'=>'example',
    'name'=>'john',
    'class'=>'normal'
);
$data = str_replace("=", '="', http_build_query($array, null, '" ', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986)).'"';
echo $data;
```

**Output**

`attr1="value1" id="example" name="john" class="normal"`

Comment: Be warned, attributes as 'xmlns'=>"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" doesn't play very well.

Comment: Use `urldecode` around `http_build_query` as http_build_query automatically encodes characters for URL, otherwise href="mailto:email@address" will be translated to href="mailto%3Aemail%40address"

Answer (score 6):

Use a `foreach` loop to get the value and key.

```
$array = array(
  'attr1'=>'value1',
  'id'=>'example',
  'name'=>'john',
  'class'=>'normal');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  echo $key . '="' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '" ';
}
```

If you wanted to use a function, you could just make your own such as the following.

```
$array = array(
  'attr1'=>'value1',
  'id'=>'example',
  'name'=>'john',
  'class'=>'normal');

echo buildTag($array);

function buildTag ($array) {
  $tag = '';
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $tag .= $key . '="' . htmlspecialchars($value) . '" ';
  }
  return $tag;
}
```

Comment: of course there is the assumption that both keys and values are valid HTML attributes and values - also no escaping must be required (ex. a double quote in a value `"` would break things)

Comment: Yes you're completely right, however, I was going under the assumptions which the user would be using this piece properly

Answer (score 6):

I use the following function:

```
function buildAttributes($attributes)
{
    if (empty($attributes))
        return '';
    if (!is_array($attributes))
        return $attributes;

    $attributePairs = [];
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $val)
    {
        if (is_int($key))
            $attributePairs[] = $val;
        else
        {
            $val = htmlspecialchars($val, ENT_QUOTES);
            $attributePairs[] = "{$key}=\"{$val}\"";
        }
    }

    return join(' ', $attributePairs);
}
```

It correctly escapes special html characters and supports boolean attributes (attributes without value). The following input:

```
[
    'name' => 'firstname',
    'value' => 'My Name',
    'required'
]
```

Will produce:

```
name="firstname" value="My Name" required
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also utilize [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) in conjunction with [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to build your `$key=$value` string.

Wrapped in [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove empty items and ultimately use [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to glue your items together.

```
$array = array(
    'attr1' => 'value1',
    'id'    => 'example',
    'name'  => 'john',
    'class' => 'normal',
    'c'     => null,
    'd'     => '',
    'e'     => '"abc"'
);

$attributes = implode( ' ', array_filter( array_map( function ( $key, $value ) {
    return $value ? $key . '="' . htmlspecialchars( $value ) . '"' : false;
}, array_keys( $array ), $array ) ) );


echo "<div " . $attributes . "></div>";
```

**Result:**

```
<div attr1="value1" id="example" name="john" class="normal" e="&quot;abc&quot;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest one-line function to do that would be:

```php
function add_attributes($attributes){
      return urldecode(http_build_query(array_map(function($v){ return '"'.((string) $v).'"'; }, $attributes), '', ' '));
}
```

You can use it like this:

```php
$array=array(
    'attr1'=>'value1',
    'id'=>'example',
    'name'=>'john',
    'class'=>'normal'
);

echo '<div '.add_attributes($array).'></div>';
```

will produce:

```html
<div attr1="value1" id="example" name="john" class="normal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
public static function arrayToStringTags( $array )
{
    $tags = '';

    if(!(is_array($array) && !empty($array)))
    {
        return $tags;
    }

    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $tags .= $key. '="'. $value. '" ';
    }

    return $tags;
}
```

Comment: Add some text to explain the answer which is pure code.

Comment: To be honest, most other answers do not provide any explanation either...