# Arrays with keys to custom string php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this array

```
Array ( [13] => 500 [16] => 1000 )
Array ( [12] => 1 [13] => 1111 )
```

how can I make them a string as this shape

```
13 500, 16 1000
12 1, 13 1111
```

Comment: Please see: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), What have you tried, etc?

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37884980/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$input = [13 => 500, 16 => 1000];
$output = implode(', ', array_map(
                function ($v, $k) {
            return $k . " " . $v;
        }, $input, array_keys($input))
);
var_dump($output);
```

Using [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
$input = [13 => 500, 16 => 1000];
$output = "";
foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
    $output .= $k . " " . $v . ", ";
}
$output = rtrim($output, ", ");
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: @HaMaDa just post what have you tried in your questions, the community hates when OP doesn't try something. It' doesn't matter if it's wrong

Comment: @HaMaDa I will help you update your question just add your code

Comment: how it would be ?

Comment: @HaMaDa you will see my suggestion for your question. If you like it, and that was your attempt you can approve it. Next time just post your attempt, corect formated input and expected output and it will be appreciated from the community. Cheers and have a great day

Comment: This advice is demo'ed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37884980/2943403). Please look for dupes before answering. If a new question can be resolved by referencing an earlier page on SO, vote to close instead of answering. [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your issue.

```
$array = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
    
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
                
    echo " ".$key ." ". $val." ,"; 
           
}
```

[image]

Comment: That wouldn't include the `keys` in the output

Comment: That won't output the keys, just the values. A suggestions would be to test the code and see if it actually does what the OP wants before posting it. At least for one-liners like this.

Comment: it merge the value like 
500,1000

Comment: Tbh, we try to avoid answering questions where the OP hasn't shown _any_ attempt on their end _at all_. Answering questions like that basically just turns SO into a free coding service, which is not what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you searching for a function with multiple pair array values (as you describe)
and each result should be the format: key1[sp]val1,[sp]key2[sp]val2  and you want an array of all these values to use later i did this function:

```
    <?php
    
    function ar(){
        $a=func_get_args();
        foreach($a as $ar){
            $s='';
            $i=0;
            $s='';
            foreach($ar as $ch =>$vl){
                $s.=$ch.' '.$vl;
                if($i<count($ar)-1){
                    $s.=', ';
                }
                $i++;
            }
            $res[]=$s;
        }
        return $res;
    }
    

/* output values by sending multiple arrays to parse */
    var_dump(ar(
        [13 => 500,16=> 1000]
        ,[12 => 1,13 => 1111]
    ));
    ?>
```